# C# Hard-coded SQL works but using SqlCommand parameters doesn't

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have some C# code that's being called to generate a string by querying a db. Originally I created the SQL by using string interpolation like the following:

```
string queryString = $"SELECT * FROM SECTION Where " +
                     $"Product_Code = (SELECT Product_Code FROM PRODUCT WHERE SHORT_NAME = '{productName}') " +
                     $"AND UPPER(description) like '{sectionName}%'";
```

This code works without issue; sectionName and productName are strings. After having read up on how SQL injection works I decided to change it to using parameters (even though this particular application doesn't need to worry about injection). Here's how I have that setup:

```
string queryString = "SELECT filename, description FROM SECTION Where " +
                "Product_Code = (SELECT Product_Code FROM PRODUCT WHERE SHORT_NAME = '@ProductCode') " +
                "AND UPPER(description) like '@SectionName%'";

var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productName;
command.Parameters.Add("@SectionName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = sectionName;
```

This is failing to get any returns. At first I thought the SQL must be different so I looked at the SQL generated from the parameters method by using the follow code:

```
string query = command.CommandText;

foreach (SqlParameter p in command.Parameters)
{
    query = query.Replace(p.ParameterName, p.Value.ToString());
}
```

According to the above code the SQL generated by either method is the same. If I execute the query created by using the parameters method in SSMS I get the proper returns so it appears to be correctly formatted. I would like to use the parameters method simply because it seems like best practice but I can't figure out why it's not getting returns while the hard-coded version is getting returns.  What could I be overlooking or not understanding?

Comment: In your SQL, `'@ProductCode'` is a string literal, not a parameter. Remove the quotes. For your `like` statement use `@SectionName + '%'`

Comment: Okay I get it now. I only needed the 's because of interpolation in the first string. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the correct way:

```
string queryString = 
@"SELECT filename, description 
FROM SECTION 
Where Product_Code = (
SELECT Product_Code 
FROM PRODUCT 
WHERE SHORT_NAME = @ProductCode
) 
AND UPPER(description) like @SectionName";

var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
command.Parameters.Add("@ProductCode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = productName;
command.Parameters.Add("@SectionName", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = "%" + sectionName + "%";
```

Answer (score 1):

The SQL that gets generated has your variable name in quotes.  It should be:

```
string queryString = "SELECT filename, description FROM SECTION Where " +
            "Product_Code = (SELECT Product_Code FROM PRODUCT WHERE SHORT_NAME = @ProductCode) " +
            "AND UPPER(description) like '%' + @SectionName + '%'";
```